# How to integrate SVN in sonarQube for analysis

Tags: sonarqube, tortoisesvn, sonarqube-scan

I need to integrate SVN with SonarQube.

Is this possible? Somewhere I read that we need to have a local project folder to have this work.

Can anyone provide steps to integrate SVN with SonarQube.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not very clear to me (especially the relation with tortoisesvn). SonarQube is analyzing source code, and you have to run a SonarQube scanner on the source files you have previously checked out.

While analyzing source file content, SonarQube can also use SCM informations (blame) for various features, like issue auto-assignment. The scanner should detect that source files are coming from an SVN repository (thanks to the .svn file located at the root) and will run the blame command on every files.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. My question was whether we should check out the source code for the analyzing source code or to directly run it on svn. Your answer clarifies my doubt.